# Is it possible to marshal native struct array to managed array with out a for loop

Tags: c++, interop, c++-cli, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm using a native DLL. I'm not sure, but I think I can't use PInvoke decl's with it since it does not export any functions and does not have a manifest. The DLL is delivered with a header file, explaining how to use it. The header file defines countless structs, enums and one class to be constructed using a factory method which is accessed via a Windows function `::GetProcAddress` (security through obscurity).
This class holds functions I would like to use in managed code.

I have successfully wrapped the class in a CLI ref class and can call trivial methods on it, wrapping those as well.

I'm going through the process of converting some structs from the header file to managed structs. For example, Native structs:

```
struct FooACL{
    int               action;                
    unsigned long     from,to;               
    char              comment[64]; 
    int               reserved[17];          
};
```

Turns into managed struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Sequential, CharSet = CharSet::Ansi)]
public value struct ManagedFooACL{
     int   action;                
     int   from,to;     
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
     String^    comment;
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::ByValArray, SizeConst = 17)]
     array<int>^ reserved;
};
```

As far as I can tell this should make the managed struct blittable? And any other struct that follows a similar pattern or levels of nested structure. As long as a layout is specified and none blittable are adorned with MarshalAs, will the structure as a whole be blittable?

And so, I'm attempting to see if there is a way to use `Marshal::Copy` or `Marshal::PtrToStructure` to convert an `FooACL*` array to `array<ManagedFooACL>^`.

I get the FooACL* array from a function call; I do not allocate it myself.

```
int total;
FooACL* foos = unamagedClass->GetFooACLS(&total);
```

`total` is an in/out that gets the size of the array returned.

What I managed to do so far, and what work is:

```
ManagedFooACL first = static_cast<ManagedFooACL>(Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(&foos [0]), ManagedFooACL::typeid));
```

What I can't wrap my mind around is why this does not:

```
array<ManagedFooACL>^ mfoos = gcnew array<ManagedFooACL>(total);
Marshal::PtrToStructure(IntPtr(&foos), mfoos);
```

This throws a:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=The specified structure must be blittable or have layout information.
Parameter name: structure
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=structure
```

Is there a way to copy array data in one call or do I really need to do a for loop?  It seems kind of silly with all this marshaling capability.

Comment: Note: If you can access the function using `GetProcAddress`, the function is exported and could be invoked via pinvoke.

Comment: I agree, but that is only a factory function that gives me a class which holds most of the functionality I'm looking for

Comment: Right, I didn't mean it is practical to do so, just noting it for future reference. :)

Comment: The CharSet is wrong, it is Ansi.  You cannot copy arrays with PtrToStructure(), you'll have to do it one element at a time.  The point of using C++/CLI is that you don't have to do these things.

Comment: Use pining for that something like 'array<ManagedFooACL>^ mfoos = gcnew array<ManagedFooACL>(total);
pin_ptr<ManagedFooACL> ptr = &mfoos; memcpy(ptr,&foos,mfool->Length)'

Comment: @HansPassant can you please elaborate on: "The point of using C++/CLI is that you don't have to do these things." 
Are you suggesting doing direct in code translation? Like field to field assignment or a constructor that fills in all the fields?
Is there a more generalized, faster(keyboard typing) way to do this in cli?

Comment: You can directly access the unmanaged pointer and the structures in C++/CLI.  No Marshal class required.  So just copy the fields.

Comment: @HansPassant unfortunately if I did that I'd be typing till the cows come home, and thats what I'm trying to eliminate using a marshaler

Comment: If you are writing more than 7 lines of code then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant please provide an example using the sample structures in the question so that everyone could benefit from your option for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done some more research it looks like the answer is no. It is not possible to auto marshal an `array` of `struct`s without looping.

I think the main reason `struct` marshaling works with `PtrToStructure` is because the structure is static/predefined. The compiler knows how to lay out the memory. Since, you get a dynamic size `array` there's no way to specify the memory lay out ahead of time. So you must loop dynamic number of `struct`s.

Alternatively, if you knew that you will always be getting an array of X length, you could define your own managed `struct` holding one element, namely the array of `ManagedFooACL` with a `ByValArray` and `SizeConst` value of X, and just cast the native `array` to the `struct`.